# overflow: hiddenが指定された要素を持つinline-blockの高さが親の高さと違う理由

Tags: css

下記のようなHTML/CSSの場合に、クラス`wrapper`とクラス`inline`・`overflow`の高さが異なってしまうのはどうしてでしょうか？

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="inline">
        <div class="overflow">あいうえお</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { border: 1px solid red; }

.inline {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}

.overflow {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uwy4djwj/)

Comment: div2 の `display: inline-block` と div3 の `overflow: hidden` どちらか片方でも欠けると、div1 の高さが div2, div3 と等しくなるのにも関わらず、両方が揃うと異なってしまうことが疑問、ということで良いでしょうか。OKならば、本文にその旨記載しておくと、読んだ人が理解しやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問のものは、 [vertical-align を調整することで](http://jsfiddle.net/higon/96b8zgsr/) 挙動を調整できます。

理由ですが、これはデフォルトの `vertical-align: baseline` の設定が作用しているためで、「通常であれば、文字の垂直位置」が対象になるところ、 `overflow:hidden` が指定されたことによって、「要素ボックスの垂直位置」が対象になったためです。

[CSS 2.1 仕様の 10.8.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#strut) の最後で以下のように規定された動きからきています。

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

参考: Stackoverflow, [CSS inline-block causing extra space between 2 vertical divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529077/css-inline-block-causing-extra-space-between-2-vertical-divs)

以下、サンプルを挙げます。

```css
span,
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>問題の構造</h3>

<div>■■<span style="display: inline-block"><div style="overflow: hidden;">□□</div></span>■■</div>

<h3>問題の構造 (さらに単純化)</h3>

<div>■■<span style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">□□</span>■■
</div>

<h3>変更: hidden 無し</h3>

<div>■■<span style="display: inline-block"><div>□□</div></span>■■</div>

<h3>変更: vertical-align: top</h3>

<div>■■<span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><div style="overflow: hidden; ">□□</div></span>■■</div>

<h3>変更: vertical-align: bottom</h3>

<div>■■<span style="display: inline-block; ; vertical-align: bottom;"><div style="overflow: hidden">□□</div></span>■■</div>
```

以上の例は [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/higon/re00op7d/) にも置きました。

Answer (score 3):

[本家stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310690/overflowhidden-on-inline-block-adds-height-to-parent) に同様の質問がありました。

これによると、原因としては、`overflow:hidden` の指定によってインラインブロックがベースラインに動かされるため、のようです。

そのため、この問題を回避したい場合は、インラインブロックの要素に `vertical-align: top;` を指定すれば高さもそろいます。